# Java Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have created 2 helper classes in the same package, one of them is for **constants** and the other is for **methods** and they are in a poject called '**Logic**'

I use those classes in another project called '**Tools**'. Classes in '**Tools**' project can see and access **constants class** in **runtime** but cannot see **methods class** in **runtime** and throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception although they are both seen and accessible in code, and projects are compiled without errors.

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: Project may compile, but at runtime those jars are needed to be available in classpath. else you will get this exception

Comment: Hey @SufyanTamadan, welcome to SO! In order to have us help you, I would recommend reading the post about [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure you get the answer you're looking from.

Comment: how you are running your code?

Comment: I checked dependencies and class path and they are already added to 'Tools' project.

Comment: They most stunning thing that one of them is working while the other isn't

Comment: These are the kind of problem we can't really solve without seeing your entire project in front uf us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my experience, the most probably reason for a NoClassDefFoundError is an error in a static initialization of the class.

When java loads a class the first time, the static initializers are performed. If you have an exception during this, a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown. So maybe there is an oversight exception before the first NoClassDefFoundError.

This exception prior to NoClassDefFoundError can also be a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: much appreciated  @Joachim . This is the cause of the problem and I solved it.